# how do you copy the contents of reference to a stl vector to another stl vector?

Tags: c++, vector

how do you copy the contents of reference to a stl vector to another stl vector
by using an assingment operator?

If given vector with contents of random numbers

```
vector <int> smallVector(smallSize);
```

and you want to copy the contents inside:

```
vector <int> copySmallVector(smallSize);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most intuitive and idiomatic way would be to initialize the second vector as you would any built-in type, using *copy initialization*. This just works:

```
vector<int> copySmallVector = smallVector;
```

There are other alternatives, using other [`std::vector` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). In this case, *copy initialization* is idiomatic, clear and easy to reason, and no knowledge of other constructors is required.